# Rate limiting API Mulesoft

Tags: mulesoft, anypoint-studio, rate-limiting, anypoint-platform, anypoint-api-manager

I know there is the Rate limiting policy for request control, but I would like to know if I don't use this policy in my API, is there a default limit value or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use use a policy then it's functionality is not used at all.

Comment: Yes, but it's not possible to accept an unlimited number of requests, there must be a default allowed value.

Comment: At some point if load increases the application is going be impacted by insufficient resources in the system. That is not the same as intentional rate limiting. The errors will be more random, depending on the application